# Caching wp-content of WordPress site behind AWS CloudFront

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I basically have this working. There is a CloudFront Distribution, Caching Behaviors, and via Route 53 A records are configured to point to CloudFront.

The problem is that everything in /wp-content/* is not being cached. I assume the setting are incorrect:

```
Viewer Protocol Policy: HTTP and HTTPS
Allowed HTTP Methods: Get, Head, Options, Put, Post, Patch, Delete
Cached HTTP Methods: Check Options
Forward Headers: Whitelist
Whitelist Headers: Host and Origin
Object Caching: Custom
Minimum TTL: 604800
Forward Cookies: None
Query String Forwarding and Caching: Forward all, cache based on all
Smooth Streaming: No
Restrict Viewer Access: No
Compress Objects Automatically: Yes
```

[Here](https://www.interactpoint.net/tiki-index.php?page=WordPress%20AWS%20CloudFront) are some of my notes.

Comment: You've done a very nice job with the notes.  Point of clarification:  *"everything in /wp-content/\* is not being cached."* -- does that mean not everything is cached but some things are, or absolutely nothing is being cached ("not everything is" vs. "nothing is")?  Capture some response headers from multiple requests for the same example object, and explain your conclusion that caching isn't working, please.

Comment: For example: /wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/resizable.min.js has a Hit of 73% where /wp-content/uploads/2015/08/deciding_to_sell-300x200.jpg has a Hit of 0%

Comment: Reviewing the CloudFront Popular Objects Report it looks like the /wp-content/* is starting to cache... maybe the setting are correct and it just took a bit for the caching to kick in... I made a few changes eailer to match the notes, maybe those took a bit of time to kick in too.